# Close javascript popup after form submission & update parent page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a popup from index.ejs, called math.ejs. After pressing the submit Ok button, I want the math.ejs popup to close and to show the calculated value on index.ejs. But right now, when I press the submit button, the popup goes to index.ejs and updates it there; it does not close. It does not update it on the normal index.ejs browser page. I have to refresh that page for it to update.

Here is what I have tried with my code:

```
<form class="" action="/index" method="post" name="mathform">
      <p>Value: <%= myValue %></p>
      <button class="btn btn-md" name="button" value="confirm" onclick="CloseAndRefresh();">Ok</button>
</form>

<script language="javascript">
      function CloseAndRefresh() {
      opener.location.reload(true);
      setTimeout(function() {
      window.close();
      }, 3000);
     }
</script>
```

I was sure this would work because it tells the parent window to reload, I even set a timer before the popup closes. Thank you for any help!

Comment: When you click the submit button, the form gets submitted. so the page navigates to /index . You will have to use ajax to send the post request and after the response is received, call `CloseAndRefresh`

Comment: @Shazvi is there a simple tutorial I can follow? I have never used Ajax before. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to get you started.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="" action="/index" method="post" name="mathform" onsubmit="submitForm(event)">
      <p>Value: <%= myValue %></p>
      <button class="btn btn-md" name="button" value="confirm">Ok</button>
</form>

<script language="javascript">
    function submitForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the form from getting submitted and navigating to /index

        $.post("/index",{
            // add your post field values here
            field1: "value1",
            field2: "value2",   
        })
            .done(function(data){ // ajax request completed successfully
                CloseAndRefresh();
            })
            .fail(function(error) { // ajax request failed
                // TODO: handle error accordingly
                CloseAndRefresh();
            });
    }

    function CloseAndRefresh() {
        opener.location.reload(true);
        // this timeout can be removed since the page refresh has already started at this point
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.close();
        }, 3000);
    }
</script>
```

Ajax requests are generally easier using jQuery. I included the the library in the code above but ideally you should add it in `<head>`. Here I'm using the `$.post` function ([documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/))

Comment: @sukiyo if this solved your issue, please mark it as answered